# Postgresql: Insert number in language specific format

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, internationalization

How can I insert number in language specific format to Postgresql database (locale are set)? Numbers are like this: `2,4` or: `4,5` (comma instead dot - that is correct in many languages). Should I convert them to the "doted" format before insert? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `lc_numeric` must be set appropriately, for example

```
test=> SHOW lc_numeric;
┌────────────┐
│ lc_numeric │
├────────────┤
│ de_DE.UTF8 │
└────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Then you can

```
INSERT INTO mytab (numcol) VALUES (to_number('2,4', '99999999D99999999'));
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE) for the meaning of the format string.